If a user removed then how can I see what I've lost
When a user is removed, the first question that comes to mind is what I've lost?

One case the upvotes/downvotes that you may lose. This is not really important.
The other case is that you may lose an answer of yours.

So, how to find them back?

There is a query in the StackExchange API that

Returns user's full reputation history, including private events.

See it here

API /me/reputation-history/full


Cool, so you get a -100 and a link to the deleted page back? Can you still access your answer?

@MaartenBodewes from the last lost points, I've seen only the lost upvotes. I cannot very deleted questions. Note >100 lost points cumulative of some people. But if you lost some due to deletion, it should be appear in there.
